# Cardinality of a subset of euclidean space

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, combinatorics, cardinals

Let $0<h, r\in \mathbb{R}$ be given and let $V\subseteq \mathcal{R}^k$ be the point $u, v\in\mathbb{R}^k$ such that $2h<||u-v||\leq r$. In my reseach, I need to find cardinality of $B(u, s)\cap V$.

Indeed, let $u\in\mathbb{R}^k$ and $s>0$ be given. In a paper, Author claim that
\begin{equation}
|B(u, s)\cap V|\leq (1+\frac{s}{h})^k
\end{equation}
but it is not clear for me.
Please help me to know it. In the case of $k=1$, proof is clear.

Comment: I think the authors are using $|A|$ for the Lebesgue measure of $A$, not its cardinality.

Comment: @geetha290krm, Thanks, I think $B(u, s)\cap V$ is a finite set.